# Swipe Events in Meteor

Tags: meteor, swipe

How do I add mobile swipe left/right events in Meteor?

I've tried...

```
Template.NAME.events({
    'swipeleft': function(){ //DO SOMETHING }
})
```

I've also tried using chriswessels/meteor-hammer package,

```
Template.NAME.gestures({
    'swipeleft .img-contain': function(){
        alert("test")
    },
    'tap': function(){
        alert("test")
    },
})
```

Neither of those methods worked.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [hammer:hammer package?](https://atmospherejs.com/hammer/hammer)

Seems like work pretty good.

You can configurate like this.

```
Template.NAME.rendered = function(){
  $('body').hammer({
    drag_min_distance:1,
    swipe_velocity:0.1
  });
};
```

And this `Events`

```
Template.NAME.events({
'swipeleft #hammerDiv': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do cool stuff here
  },
'swiperight #hammerDiv': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do cool stuff here
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. Is $('body').hammer() necessary on top of the event func?

Comment: @Ethaan It doesnt work `$('body').hammer is not a function`. This package has been flagged at the meteor page